# Tired of having no data despite having plenty of bars

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, t-mobile, baseband

I'm on T-Mobile US with a Google Galaxy Nexus, I don't use WiFi, and I've grown to be very tired of very often having some spots around town where I get great (or sometimes even excellent) HSPA+ reception, yet, nonetheless, get basically no data working at all -- even phone calls don't connect.

Going into the `*#*#INFO#*#*` *Testing* menu, *Phone info* screen, and selecting *GSM only* in place of *WCDMA preferred*, and then, after the phone connects onto *EDGE*, then manually selecting to go back to the WCDMA preference as above, generally fixes the issue, and data starts flowing again.  I also recently noticed that every time this has happened, the *Location* *CID* value when in UMTS/HSPAP, is different between the working and non-working states, and, in a given geographical location, some CIDs always appear to not work, and some to always work.

Why is this happening?  Why is the phone/baseband not smart enough to abandon the broken cell towers, and automatically connect to working ones, if that's actually what happens once you force it into EDGE, and then back to WCDMA?  (I guess the better question would be -- why isn't TMUS monitoring these broken cells, but that'd be for a different SE property.)

Comment: If the device is rooted, you can change the network mode easily (in fact with just one touch) or based on location. So, is the device rooted?

Comment: Also sometimes from updates and whatnot the modem/radio files need to be refreshed. You could try flashing new/updated modem/radio files for your device. You can find the files needed in the factory images, found on Google's nexus page. https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en

Comment: Alternatively, that interface where you change the network mode can also be launched based on touch, gesture or location. Point is, what would you like to have as a solution? @jer3my also has a good alternative.

Comment: Also another thing to try and look into. Make sure you are using the correct APN settings for your network. Once again from time to time. Updating your device could change and or mess with the settings. Not sure on your device but the APN settings on my Nexus 6 are located in Settings > More(under mobile data) / Cellular settings > Access Point Names.

Comment: One more thing: does activating airplane mode and then inactivating it helps? Since you go from WCDMA pref -> GSM (Edge) -> back to WCDMA pref, Airplane mode should help.

Comment: @Firelord, airplane mode sometimes help, sometimes not; it's annoying that it also disables the hotspot, so, my tethered devices drop the wifi connection

Comment: @jer3my, but why would it be APN if the data works just fine at least half of the time?

Comment: @cnst You could be using older APN settings. But now that I think about it. Tmobile uses sim cards. So when you put in the sim card and turn on the device. It should of pulled the correct APN settings then. Just wondering too. How long has this been going on? Just recently or off and on since you had the device? Maybe Tmobile is doing maintenance in your area.

Comment: @jer3my, I don't recall this happening too often with T-Mobile US HSPA+ before, would usually only happen when on EDGE in some hard-to-reach places, but maybe I was just paying less attention.  How would it be acceptable to be doing maintenance like that for days?  Why not shutdown the HSPA+ cell if it's malfunctioning like that?

Comment: @cnst no idea but I can tell you carriers do it. At least Sprint did. They were redoing the entire network here in Chicago-land area. Text would be hours late. Phone calls wouldn't come through. Data wasn't working. It was a rough time. Lol

Comment: @jer3my, that's Sprint!  lol.

Comment: @cnst Oh I know. But I am sure the other carriers do it to a degree also. =p